# plotly create a vertical line to show average

Tags: javascript, plotly

So i am attempting create a horizontal bar chart that has a horizontal line showing average.

So far i have attempted the following:

First added my barChart series (it comes from the following array):

```
      "series": [
    {
      "value": 100, "label": "F1"
    },
    {
      "value": 25, "label": "F2"
    },
    {
      "value": 30, "label": "Jedi Jeremiah 555"
    },
    {
      "value": 40, "label": "F4"
    },
    {
      "value": 55, "label": "F5"
    },
    {
      "value": 60, "label": "F6"
    },
    {
      "value": 71, "label": "F7"
    },
    {
      "value": 15, "label": "F8"
    },
    {
      "value": 88, "label": "F9"
    },
    {
      "value": 90, "label": "F10"
    }
  ]
```

Which converts to an array of the following objects:

```
{name: 'F1', orientation: "h", x: [100], y: ["F1"]}
```

Then afterwards i add the following series:

```
{
    name: 'average organization',
    type: 'scatter',
    x: [60],
    orientation: 'h'
}
```

This creates the following chart:

[image]

As you can see there is only a blue dot indicating the average which is not the result im looking for.

I know that there are shapes however i wish to have it as a part of the chart so that you can either select or deselect it.

Does anyone know how you might achieve this?

Comment: You got a point as you define just a point. Instead you should provide data for each bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help if you would provide a jsFiddle or codePen or other example to execute it directly:-)
I think the problem is, that you want to have a vertical line but set `orientation: 'h'` to the last "average-organisation"-object instead using `orientation: 'v'`.

I reproduced your example in a jsFiddle and add the desired behaviour:
https://jsfiddle.net/vepycde0/

Hope it helps:-)

**Edit**: For hiding the "0" on yAxis use `y: [""]` as seen in that jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vepycde0/1/

Comment: Thank you @fillperweid. Is there a way to remove the 0 from the legend?

Comment: I think the only way is to provide an empty y-value for it: `y: [""]`. I updated my jsFiddle for you: jsfiddle.net/vepycde0/1